# Strip non numeric characters and convert to Float field

Tags: solr, filter

I'm trying to use a copyField command to take a text field which contain numeric values but has some associated text into a numeric field which can be range filtered.

eg.  normal values 1.3 or 200
     dirty values 200cc or 1,500

Is it possible to setup a Float field type that will use a filter to strip out the non numeric characters?

If I define it like this, the filter doesn't seem to be processing

```
    <fieldType name="floatNoText" class="solr.TrieFloatField" >
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^0-9.]" replacement="" replace="all"/>
    </fieldType>
```

If I define it with an analyzer :

```
    <fieldType name="floatNoText" class="solr.TrieFloatField" >
        <analyzer>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^0-9.]" replacement="" replace="all"/>
    </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I get the following error :

SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: analyzer without class or tokenizer & filter list

Is there a way to setup a numeric field so you can apply a filter to it?
Or can I make it so that the source field is presenting a stripped version of the data to the copy field?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below field type :-

```
<fieldType name="numericOnly" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^0-9]+" replacement="" replace="all" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This should store only numeric values and replace everything else. You can fine tune the regex to your needs.
Also, this will just apply to the indexed value.
This value would not be stored and hence the value retrieved with still be alphanumeric.

Comment: That's good but it doesn't convert it to a float type. You need a numeric type to support range queries correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess he wants the field to be of type TrieFloatField as it will run range queries etc that will be more performant than if it was just a text field.

So one way to do it is by using an [update processor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) and you can do the cleanup there, and insert the proper numeric value into a field.